# Cannot put a date as a default value in sqlite manager

Tags: sqlite, sqlitemanager

I have a DATETIME column.

I want the default to be `1970-01-01 00:00:00`

When I enter that as the value, sqliemanager complains that it isn't valid - something about the dash? But sqlite date data always has dashes.

What exactly is the value I put in the "default" box to put the date `1970-01-01 00:00:00` as the default date, for a DATETIME column?

Answer (score 0):

SQLite [has no `DATETIME` type](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

If your column contains strings in the format `1970-01-01 00:00:00`, then your default value must also be a string: `DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:00'`